# Failed to ping node [nodeId=null]

Tags: java, ignite

we have an Ignite setup (apache-ignite-2.13.0-1,Zulu Java 11.0.13, RHEL 8.6) with 3 server nodes and ~20 clients joining the topology as client nodes. The client application additionally also connects via JDBC. The application is from a 3rd party vendor, so I don't know what they are doing internally.

Since some time we see that always one of the 3 servers logs a huge amount of these warnings:

[12:40:41,446][WARNING][tcp-disco-ip-finder-cleaner-#7-#62][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to ping node [nodeId=null]. Reached the timeout 60000ms. Cause: Connection refused (Connection refused)

It did not always do that, Ignite and the application were updated multiple times, and at some point this started showing up.

I don't understand what this means. All the nodes I see in the topology with ignitevisor have a nodeId set, but here it is null. All server nodes and clients have full connectivity between each on all high ports. All expected nodes are shown in the topology.

So what is this node with nodeId=null? How can I find more about where that comes from?

Regards,
Sven

Comment: Can you please share a complete log from the problematic node somewhere? Or a snippet from some timeframe with that warning?

Comment: Hi Alexandr, I have uploaded a log to pastebin. I had to remove some internal info, I hope it's still helpful. The error message always shows up only on one of the 3 server nodes. To get a short log with the error, I restarted server ign3 first, then restarted the other 2 servers one after another, so the error moved over to server ign3. https://pastebin.com/Z5NGinU4

Comment: Thanks, the logs seems to be fine to me. Does your cluster work well in general and the issue is about these annoying messages?

Comment: Looking at the logs & source code, I suppose this message comes from IpFinderCleaner that periodically checks the nodes for availability and cleans IPs set if required. https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/f4467bc32e46b5941a56a3f87db1a3e8a398e413/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ServerImpl.java#L2285

Comment: What IpFinder do you use? Can you please share your TcpDiscoverySpi settings?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UqkFKQrt

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin Hello, I also have the same annoying log messages, they started to appear long ago (although they do not prevent the cluster to work properly). But there is no anwser from the Ignite team by now: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ignite.apache.org/msg32804.html, https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ignite.apache.org/msg33472.html

Comment: And there is  already a ticket for this (with no updates): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16989

Comment: @IlyaRublev Yes, it looks like the message has been added in some release with the improper severity. I believe it's harmless but rather annoying?

Comment: This message has been introduced in 2.11, by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14377 I think you can ignire it, but agree, at least we should make it single entry instead of writing it repetitevely

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it up,

- the message was introduced in 2.11 in order to provide additional logging to communication and networking.
- The warning itself just means that a node might not be accessible from the current one, i.e. we can't ping that node. That is normal in many cases and you can ignore this warning.
- The implementation seems to be quite incorrect, we'd like to write it down only first time instead of having a bunch of duplicate messages. Plus, that type of logging information used to be the DEBUG one, whereas now it's become more severe - WARN for no reason.
- There is an open [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16989) for an improvement.